# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getEndpointUrl() on null in /home/magento/backend/app/code/Wac/InstagramFeed/Model/Api/AbstractApi.php:124

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, php

[image]

the above image
The **getendpointUrl** getting null

```
public function getEndpointUrl(): string
    {
    return $this->getStoreConfigValue(self::XML_PATH_INSTAGRAM_API_ENDPOINT_URL);
}



XML_PATH_INSTAGRAM_API_ENDPOINT_URL it contains value it working fine
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in name of variable $this->apiHelper

you must inject $this->apiHelper with helper class in constructor.

and

protected $this->apiHelper;